# Visual Studio publish error "Failed to determine the https port for redirect"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to connect my database using API by using

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tool
MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
Swashbukle.AspNetCore 
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
```

Code is working very well inside Visual Studio 2022, however, the app is not working when I tried to publish it, I get this error

> Warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3] Failed to determine the https port for redirect

How can I resolve that?

Thanks a lot

I tried to delete the `.vs` folder and it didn't work

Comment: Sound like a proxy issue.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0  The port could be blocked by a firewall or virus checker.

Comment: I checked it already and I don't use any proxy. The code is working normally with throw visual Studio rebuild, also it works when I run it using dotnet run in the terminal of the main project near the SLN

Comment: Are you publishing to a Folder which will create a setup.exe folder.  Also see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1297509/how-to-fix-this-error-warn-microsoft-aspnetcore-ht